# color_quant::NeuQuant compiled to WebAssembly outputs zero values

Tags: rust, webassembly

I am trying to load an image in the browser and use the NewQuant algorithm to quantize my image buffer it in Rust via WebAssembly. However, the NewQuant output contains zero values, regardless of what PNG I try to feed it.

I expose two Rust methods to WASM:

1. `alloc` for allocating a byte buffer
2. `read_img` which will read and process the img buffer

I know that I get zero values because I imported a JavaScript method called `log_nr` for logging simple `u8` numbers. The buffer seems to contain valid pixel values.

```
extern crate color_quant;
extern crate image;

use color_quant::NeuQuant;
use image::{DynamicImage, GenericImage, Pixel, Rgb};

use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::mem;
use std::os::raw::c_void;

static NQ_SAMPLE_FACTION: i32 = 10;
static NQ_PALETTE_SIZE: usize = 256;

extern "C" {
    fn log(s: &str, len: usize);
    fn log_nr(nr: u8);
}

fn get_pixels(img: DynamicImage) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut pixels = Vec::new();

    for (_, _, px) in img.pixels() {
        let rgba = px.to_rgba();

        for channel in px.channels() {
            pixels.push(*channel);
        }
    }

    pixels
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn alloc(size: usize) -> *mut c_void {
    let mut buf = Vec::with_capacity(size);
    let ptr = buf.as_mut_ptr();
    mem::forget(buf);

    return ptr as *mut c_void;
}

fn process_img(img: DynamicImage) {
    let pixels: Vec<u8> = get_pixels(img);
    let quantized = NeuQuant::new(NQ_SAMPLE_FACTION, NQ_PALETTE_SIZE, &pixels);

    let q = quantized.color_map_rgb();

    for c in &q {
        unsafe {
            log_nr(*c);
        }
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn read_img(buff_ptr: *mut u8, buff_len: usize) {
    let mut img: Vec<u8> = unsafe { Vec::from_raw_parts(buff_ptr, buff_len, buff_len) };

    return match image::load_from_memory(&img) {
        Ok(img) => {
            process_img(img);
        }
        Err(err) => {
            let err_msg: String = err.to_string().to_owned();
            let mut ns: String = "[load_from_memory] ".to_owned();

            ns.push_str(&err_msg);

            unsafe {
                log(&ns, ns.len());
            }
        }
    };
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello from rust 2");
}
```

The JavaScript code is the following:

```
run('sample.png');

function run(img) {
    return compile().then(m => {
        return loadImgIntoMem(img, m.instance.exports.memory, m.instance.exports.alloc).then(r => {
            return m.instance.exports.read_img(r.imgPtr, r.len);
        });
    })
}

function compile(wasmFile = 'distil_wasm.gc.wasm') {
    return fetch(wasmFile)
        .then(r => r.arrayBuffer())
        .then(r => {
            let module = new WebAssembly.Module(r);
            let importObject = {}
            for (let imp of WebAssembly.Module.imports(module)) {
                if (typeof importObject[imp.module] === "undefined")
                    importObject[imp.module] = {};
                switch (imp.kind) {
                case "function": importObject[imp.module][imp.name] = () => {}; break;
                case "table": importObject[imp.module][imp.name] = new WebAssembly.Table({ initial: 256, maximum: 256, element: "anyfunc" }); break;
                case "memory": importObject[imp.module][imp.name] = new WebAssembly.Memory({ initial: 256 }); break;
                case "global": importObject[imp.module][imp.name] = 0; break;
                }
            }

            importObject.env = Object.assign({}, importObject.env, {
                log: (ptr, len) => console.log(ptrToStr(ptr, len)),
                log_nr: (nr) => console.log(nr),
            });

            return WebAssembly.instantiate(r, importObject);
        });
}

function loadImgIntoMemEmscripten(img) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        fetch(img)
            .then(r => r.arrayBuffer())
            .then(buff => {
                const imgPtr = Module._malloc(buff.byteLength);
                const imgHeap = new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, imgPtr, buff.byteLength);

                imgHeap.set(new Uint8Array(buff));

                resolve({ imgPtr });
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: Your previous question ([Can't get image::load_from_memory() to work when compiled to WebAssembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50415623/155423) indicates that you can't use `image::load_from_memory` in WebAssembly, yet this code uses it. Something doesn't seem correct here.

Comment: @Shepmaster somebody on reddit suggested that the problem came from an extra feature which wasn't compatible with WASM: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/8kdy58/imageload_from_memory_doesnt_work_compiled_to. I have managed to load PNG's via `image::load_from_memory`. And I am obtaining a valid `DynamicImage` object.

Comment: Via Cargo.toml I only loaded the PNG feature from the `image` extern crate.